# React-Admin v4: how to set basename with keyword after /#/

Tags: react-router, react-router-dom, react-admin

I'm trying the simplest `React Admin v4` setup to have a path structure such as `/#/{project}/resource...`, for instance `/#/project_1/user/`, `/#/project_2/user/` etc...
(I want everything under `/#/` so I can serve my app via static files).

Looking at [this guide](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/4.0/Routing.html) I have:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { Admin, Resource, CustomRoutes, ListGuesser } from "react-admin";
import { Route } from "react-router-dom";
import { BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";

let project = "project_1";

const Dashboard = () => {
  return <>Dashboard</>;
};

const Test = () => {
  return <>Test</>;
};

const App = () => {
  let basename = "/#/" + project;
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Admin dashboard={Dashboard} basename={basename}>
        <Resource name="user" list={ListGuesser} />
        <CustomRoutes>
          <Route path="/settings" element={<Test />} />
        </CustomRoutes>
      </Admin>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**What's working properly**

- The menu link paths are as desired (eg `/#/project_1/user/`)

[image]

**What's not working**

- No matter which menu link I click, it's the dashboard being displayed (even if I try the custom route at `/#/project_1/settings/` or `/#/settings`)

**What do I need to restore `resources/custom routes` while preserving the path structure with the leading `/#/{project}/`?**

*PS: I am running `RA v4`:*

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.0.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.8.1",
    "ra-data-json-server": "^3.19.11",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-admin": "4.0.0-rc.1",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.0"
  },
```

Comment: What installed version of `react-router-dom` are you using? It *looks* like v6. You need to render the `Route` components into a `Routes` component, both from `react-router-dom`.

Comment: `react-router-dom` version is `6.3.0`. `Routes` does exist, but If I replace `<Route>` with `<Routes>` I get `[Routes] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route>`. So it seems `<CustomRoute>` is already of `<Routes>` type. Doing `<Routes><Route>,,,` doesn't solve the issue (same problem as described in the question).

Comment: No no no, `Routes` component is the parent component for `Route` components, not a replacement. RRDv6 doesn't use custom routes anymore. Only the `Routes` and `Route` components are used. Would it be possible for you to create a *running* codesandbox demo of what you are trying to do that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: But `<CustomRoute>` is coming from `React Admin`, not `RRD`: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/doc/4.0/CustomRoutes.html . Does that change your comment?

Comment: No, but yes. I was going to say no, it doesn't change my comment, but before committing to that I decided to check the `react-admin` dependencies. It looks like `react-admin` has a dependency on [`react-router-dom@5.1`](https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/master/packages/react-admin/package.json#L51) so it won't work with `react-router-dom@6`. You need to roll back to a v5 version of `react-router-dom`.

Comment: I see. `v6 upgrade guide`: https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/upgrading/v5#refactor-custom-routes suggests `"waiting for the backwards compatibility package to be released"`. So between `RRD` and `RA` both being in transition, now might not be the right time to play around. I'm going to wait for both packages to stabilize and revisit come back here with a solution.

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with `react-admin`, but for RRD yeah, I've seen lots of churn here with devs confused by using outdated tutorials and such. Sorry if I caused you any confusion. Cheers and good luck.

Comment: No worries, actually made me aware of `RRD` upgrade to `v6` and potential compatibility so overall positive feedback.